# MATLAB にて、原因のわからないエラーメッセージが出ました

Tags: matlab

MATLABで、ある簡単なプログラムを作成しています。その中の関数（下記）にて、実行しようとするとエラーメッセージが出ました。その関数の内容は、ある関数に変数を飛ばし、その計算結果が100を超える場合は返り値に200を返し、そうでない場合はその計算結果をそのまま返すというものです。

```
　function T=Tx(n) 
    i=(n+3)^7
   %　i が200より大きい場合は返り値に200を返す
   if(i>200)
    T=200;
   else
    T=i; 
  end
```

上記の関数を実行しようとした際、下記のようなエラーメッセージが出ました。

```
symfunをlogicalに変換できない
　 エラー（line4)
　　 if(i>200)
```

原因がわからず、全く手も足も出ない状況です。どなたか尽力いただければ幸いです。

Comment: 二つ確認したいことがあります。1. 関数には、何をどんなふうに渡しているのでしょうか。2. `whos `コマンドを実行すると、何が表示されますか。

Comment: いくつかの関数を、あらかじめ宣言された状態で、

Comment: 間違えました、申し訳ありません。まずは、返信いただきありがとうございます。助かります。関数には、あらかじめ宣言しておいたA(t)という関数を渡しています。宣言文は以下になります、”syms A(t)”。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/81701

Answer (score 2):

Symbolic Math toolbox がインストールしてあるのですね。私もあまり詳しくはありませんが、おそらく以下のようなことが起きているのだと思います。

関数`Tx(n)`にシンボリック関数`A(t)`を渡しているので、`Tx`内の変数 i も

```
(A(t) + 3)^7
```

のようなシンボリック関数になっています。更に`if(i>200)`のところでも`i>200`も

```
200 < (A(t) + 3)^7
```

のようなシンボリック関数になります。

ここで if 文は、式ではなく文ですので、実際に`200 < (A(t) + 3)^7`を評価して、if か else 内の、どちらかを実行しようとします。しかし、`200 < (A(t) + 3)^7`はシンボリック関数 (symfun) のままで具体的な値がないので、論理値 (logical) に変換できず、エラーになっています。

何をしたいのかが、よくわからないのですが、合成関数のようなことをしたいのでしたら、`Tx(A(3))`のように、都度、具体的な値で呼ぶのではいけないのでしょうか。

Comment: お力添えいただきありがとうございます。何分、MATLABを使い慣れてないもので、恐縮です。また、実際のコマンドウィンドウ‌​では、上記のA(t)の関数を宣言した後、‌​上記の関数を、微分方程式内で解くために用‌​いています。そのため、”eqn=diff‌​(A)==7*Tx(A);”といように。